# Is there a mathematical notation of indexing a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Do matrices in linear algebra support an operation of indexing them analogous to array indexing?

For example:

$$
A =
\left [\begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4
\end{array}\right]
$$

In C, a fixed 2 by 2 array in 32 bit integer space could be described as:

```
int32_t A[][2] = {
    {1, 2}, 
    {3, 4}
};
```

and allows operations like:

```
A[0][0] = 2;
```

Is there a universally accepted equivalent to such an operation in linear algebra?

I understand that a Matrix is not a C Array equivalent, but I am curious whether such an operation is supported.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you mean. Often one will write the $(i, j)$ entry of a matrix $A$ as $A_{ij}$ or $a_{ij}$.

Comment: I mean is there a non naive, universally accepted way to denote mutation/accessing of an element within a matrix. A universally "correct" way to denote such an operation.

Comment: The notation $A_{ij}$ "accesses" the element, but if you're referring to the operation that takes a matrix $A$, indices $i, j$ and a value $b$ and returns the matrix $A'$ whose entries are $A'_{kl} = A_{kl}$ for $(k, l) \neq (i, j)$ and $A'_{ij} = b$, then no, there is no widely familiar notation for this. Of course, you can always define such a notation and explain it yourself.

Comment: I think the title of this question should be modified to make clear that the question is about a notation for _modifying_ a matrix entry.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen indexing/mutating. But from the responses I got so far, it appears a matrix is not a mutable construct, and instead new matrices must be created via transformation or reinitialization, so asking how to modify a matrix seems misleading.

Comment: It is not that a matrix is not a mutable construct, it is that mathematics deals with values, which are by nature unchanging. Not because they resist change; one can very well add the first row of a matrix to its second row, but the resulting (matrix) value is not the same as the original value, just like adding $3$ to $51$ produces a value that no longer is $51$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen you phrase that very well, but what you said does not seems to contradict my definition of an immutable contruct. The matrix you have defined cannot be changed without creating a new matrix, unless it is an identity transformation.

Comment: What I meant to say is that the notion of (im)mutable construct, though relevant in programming, is meaningless in mathematics. However that does not exclude having a notation for a value obtained by a given modification of another value (see my answer below).

Answer (score 28):

$A_{ij}$ is a common notation for the $(i,j)$th entry of a matrix $A$.

$i$ specifies the row, $j$ specifies the column, and the indexes start with $1$, rather than $0$.

So if $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$, then
$A_{11} = 1$, $A_{12} = 2$, $A_{21} = 3$, and $A_{22} = 4$.

Comment: A standard matrix is always row major then, right?

Comment: In the usual notation, the first index specifies the row.  Is that what you mean by "row major"?

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, it's row major order.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: @Dmitry: I think you've misunderstood the term "row major". Row-major order has to do with the order in computer memory or storage -- whether the elements in the same row are always adjacent, vs. whether the elements in the same column are. In math, there's nothing analogous to that.

Comment: Where I live – and I *hope* this isn’t as common elsewhere – sometimes $A$ is the matrix, $a_{ij}$ is its $(i, j)$-th entry, and $A_{ij}$ is its $(i, j)$ [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)). \*shivers\*

Comment: @ruakh Surely row major is universal because it is the order of indexing as well as storage. Indexing a column major matrix construct would be denoted as Aji rather than Aij. However I may be mistaken since A matrix has no notion of rows/columns, but rather of the "Standard Vectors"(thanks residuence)  composing it, which are always columns, and therefore must be accessed via row major. I'm not certain of that being necessary though: perhaps there are situations when it makes more sense for matrix to be defined to contain row vectors, but I can't think of any.

Comment: @Dmitry: Re: "Indexing a column major matrix construct would be denoted as Aji rather than Aij": Nonsense. Languages/libraries that use column-major order still write the row index first. The only time you'd write the column index first is if you have a language/library that uses row-major order, and you want to simulate column-major order by using the language/library's rows as your columns and vice versa.

Comment: @ruakh That's because all languages are built on arrays being row major. This is a design constraint not an absolute constraint. It is possible to support both, but generally row major is better because it heavily improves locality, use of cache lines. I am certain it is possible to augment a language to be able to choose whether the matrix is row or column major in both storage and accessing.

Comment: @Dmitry: Again, nonsense. There are plenty of languages that use column-major order, including some of the earliest languages (e.g. Fortran). That's why the terms "row major" and "column major" even exist. But they all use the normal math notation, with the row index preceding the column index. (If they didn't, then there would actually be no difference between row-major and column-major orders: if you flip the notation *and* the storage, then the two flips cancel each other out.)

Comment: @ruakh maybe i didn't wrap my mind around it properly. You might be right, the two flips would cancel each other out and it would make no difference. I was thinking in terms of HTML tr/td analogy to arrays, but unlike HTML, there is no "visual aspect" so flipping tr and td would net no difference in terms of storage:representation, it would still be accessed the same way, arrays can't tell rows from columns, it is us that give those meanings to it when we use them. We are free to think of them as columns, rows and the array won't care. For some reason this wasn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 16):

The most common one is $A_{ij} $, although you will often see $a_{ij} $ in lowercase. Slightly less common is $A_{i,j} $ (usually when the indices are themselves a formula). Far less common is $A (i,j) $; sometimes used when there are other subindices/superindices around.

Answer (score 10):

No, quite independently of matrices there is no standard mathematical notation for mutating operations, because there is no notion of executing a mathematical text. If we wrote a hypothetical formula with a side effect, what would make that side effect actually happen? We are free to reread our formulas if we don't quite understand them the first time around; would that make the side effect happen a twice or more?

However, it is possible to describe mathematical values in en operational way, as "the result of taking such and so value and performing this and that operation on it". Note that the meaning of such a description does not change by "executing" it, since it specifies which *value* to start with. Things like bringing matrices into echelon form are often described using this kind of description, but it usually does not use a symbolic formalism to describe just what operations are to be performed.

One case that is somewhat of this nature is evaluating polynomials by writing say $P(2)$ (although I personally prefer the more explicit $P[X:=2]$), which means (more or less) the result of taking the expression referred to by $P$ and replacing every instance of $X$ by the value $2$, and then performing the arithmetic operations (addition, multiplications, powers,...).

But for modifying a matrix value in a specific way, I don't think there is any standardised notation.

Comment: Very important point! But I think the notation $A_{00} \leftarrow 2$ could be considered “standard mathematical notation for mutation”; this is what's used for most algorithm pseudocodes in CS papers. Arguably, such mutation still doesn't really make sense mathematically though. (Mutation _can_ be described rigorously as a mathematical operation however, as a [monadic action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) for instance.)

Comment: of course there's a notion of executing mathematical text. By construction, mathematics is nothing but a bunch of symbols until it is parsed by us and in the process of walking through the statements, we implicitly transform a default environment, consisting only of reserved variables bound to reserved values such as pi, e, to new environments with the new state of the environment. Like most programming languages, math statements are chained with implicit(or explicit) "then". Every statement is a side effect in the sense that our new environment has new variables/or a new object on our stack.

Comment: When we re-read an expression, we take an arbitrary environment, that we suppose is valid at this step, and interpret the statement and see what our new environment is, and use that as the input to the next step. This is of course can easily be optimized down to "changing state", since there's no other "threads" messed up if we mutate a value.

Comment: That said, you're right, there's no actual reason to care whether we redefine a variable or not because the statement "let x = 2, let x = 3" is no different than "(λΓ.(λx. (λx ...)(3))(2))" where (λx. x) is a lambda function, and λΓ denotes our implicit environment(with pi, e, more or less variables)  and since we are allowed to have many functions that have the same named variable, mutation in a math statement is just an abstraction of lambda abstraction which allows us to use math without caring how it "works"(variable binding, concept of then, concept of environments and stacks).

Comment: My point is that math definitely has side effects, but you're right that as long as there is only one thread of reasoning, the concept of mutability is meaningless because mutability is isomorphic to shadowing(can easily convert to and from the two structures, `a=2 a=3,a=4` and the `(λΓ.(λx. (λx. (λx ...)(4))(3))(2))` that we execute by choosing an environment λΓ to start with.

Answer (score 8):

Try $ e_i^t Ae_j = a_{ij} $ where $ e_i $ the i-th Standard Vector.
$e_i = (0,…,0,1,0,….0)^t$ and the $1$ ist the i-th Element.

Comment: What does `t` denote?

Comment: Transpose the Vector

Comment: So a column Vector becomes a row Vector and the otherway around. Where $x_{j1} = x_{1j} /forall j$

Comment: Wait, so you are describing the operation through multiplication. That's clever I need a bit to wrap my mind around it. I am not sure if it is legal to reassign that value though.

Comment: I do not unterstand which value You Want to reassign.

Comment: I want to know whether it is legal to reassign a value of an element within a matrix after it has been defined; that is, whether the matrix is a mutable construct.

Comment: The matrix you would obtain by changing the value of one of the entries of $A$, is a new, different matrix which is not equal to $A$.  So it should have a new name, something other than $A$.  It's not like a variable in programming where you can just change its value.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Similar to Haskell constructs.

Comment: Wait. Is (ei)t the result of ei of the transpose of A or is ei in A and then transpose the vector? I think it's  the first.

Comment: I think it's (et)1 rather than (e1)t.

Comment: Hmm its $(e_j)^t $. You have a specific vector and then you transpose it.

Comment: I just tried to do it the other way and i got 41 as a result O.o. I may have made a mistake but I was pretty careful. I'll try the other way. Nevermind I can't. That would be multiplication of a 2x1 matrix by 2x1 matrix. I'm confused now. Nevermind it's fine, but i'm struggling to get it to result in anything that makes sense. I keep getting scalars which are over 40..

Comment: sorry for my crude attempt but this is my failed attempts: http://imgur.com/cOOHlAE.

Comment: ok lets do this: we want to calculate $a_{21}$ he elemte in row 2 column 1
$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$
so it follows
$$e_2^t A e_1 = e_2^t *  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} = 3$$.
I think you missunderstodd the definition of $e_i$. We do two different calculations:
1. Matrix multiplied by a vector which is vector
2. tranpsed vector multiplied a vector which you could know as inner prduct which is a vector

Comment: couldnt edit last comment so here is some more information
$$  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3  \end{bmatrix}$$
and 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}^t \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3  \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 3  \end{bmatrix}  = 3$$

Comment: so [1 3] * (1, 3) = 3  is not matrix multiplication, but dot product? If I understand correctly, you rotate it to truncate the vector. That's interesting.

Comment: @Dmitry, I'm a little amused by the fact that you are familiar enough with functional programming and not with math to say "oh, math notation works like Haskell" rather than the reverse. There's nothing wrong with that, though.

Comment: @MarkS I think of Math in terms of programming rather than other way around. I find programming more testable and well formed, whereas math tends to often get into misleading/naive and contradictory situations without easy ways to check without peer review. Paper math doesn't give compilation errors and is often difficult to check if what you are expressing is well formed or misleading. That's just my philosophy though. I believe math wants to be very similar to a statically typed programming language, and suffers the same issues as paper programming.

Comment: @MarkS to be more specific. There is nothing wrong with math in itself, but rather the non explicit abuses of notation, incorrect/inexplicit transformations, impact of typos, etc. Very similar to doing programming on paper, and I see no reason why math cannot be a strict language  in itself that can be statically analyzed to check for mistakes. Functional programming gave new tools to view math in ways that imperative languages wouldn't allow, such as infinite collections and lazy evalutation. Math is much harder to learn than programming as well because you can't be sure you understood it.

Comment: @MarkS well, it is easier now to check if you understood it with tools such as Wolfram alpha and calculators. But before that, you needed another person to confirm you understood it and trust that they know it as well(many professors seem difficult to trust that they understand it and are not making it up: they also make mistakes that any compiler would catch). Algorithms are unbiased if written correctly, must be compiled, and generate results you can play around with. end of wall of text.